# MySQL (python 3.6) - SELECT * FROM table - returns number of rows instead of table

Tags: python, mysql

I am working with MySQL but I have some unexpected behaviour.
I have past experience with SQLite but I guess I am missing something here.

Using the query `SELECT * FROM tableName` I would expect the content of the table to be the output.
Instead I get an int, being the count of rows in the table.
Here is the piece of code I am using.

```
import MySQLdb

conn=MySQLdb.connect(host="xxx",user="xxx",passwd="xxx")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("create database if not exists Test;")
cursor.execute("use Test;")
cursor.execute("create table if not exists City (id int not null primary key auto_increment, city varchar(50), unique(city));")
cursor.execute("insert into City (city) values ('Firenze');")
cursor.execute("insert into City (city) values ('Roma');")
conn.commit()
print(cursor.execute("select city from City;"))
```

I would expect to get:

```
Firenze
Roma
```

Instead I get:
`2`

If I run the same query from a SQL client I get the expected output. Any clever idea? 
Thanks :)

Comment: You missed the Fetchall() method to fetch the records, Could you please try the answer below and check it. @Alessandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the FetchAll() function in your code.
Fetch all is nothing but fetching the data of last executed statement.

```
import MySQLdb
conn=MySQLdb.connect(host="xxx",user="xxx",passwd="xxx")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("create database if not exists Test;")
cursor.execute("use Test;")
cursor.execute("create table if not exists City (id int not null primary key 
auto_increment, city varchar(50), unique(city));")
cursor.execute("insert into City (city) values ('Firenze');")
cursor.execute("insert into City (city) values ('Roma');")
conn.commit()
print(cursor.execute("select city from City;"))
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is `print(cursor.execute("select city from City;")` returns you the number of rows or rows count.

For the complete records use something like this

```
myresult = cursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
    print(x)
```

Comment: I already posted the same answer above, I hope this is repeated answer.